# Testing Rails Project/Application Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

There's every chance I've approached this entirely in the wrong way which might be why I'm struggling to find an answer, as is typically the way with Rails.

For clarity, I'm referring to the -m option of "rails new", eg.

`rails new [new-project] -m [this is where my template goes]`

I've created a project/application template to speed up the creation of a specific project type, with the view that further projects/products will have their own template also.

The template adds in the relevant gems and does a bit of housework to tidy up the output of the gem installation (moving JS/CSS files to /vendors, for example) as well as copying over a generator that gives the option to expand the project further.

I'm struggling to understand if there is a way to test that the project template is working as expected and copying the correct files.

Have I approached this in the correct manner, and is there a way to test project/application templates?

Edit - Further research is suggesting that an Engine may be a better solution. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rails Engine is a way to package some application or application subset so that it is easy to share with other applications. Basically, if you have some models and controllers that can be shared by multiple applications, you can use an Engine. This sounds a lot like what you described as a project template. Engines can be packaged as gems, gems can automatically behave as Engines, include rake tasks, hook into Rails initialization, and more, so why not take advantage of Other People's Work if you can?

Comment: The template I was using was essentially a delivery mechanism for further generators, so I think wrapping it up as an Engine/gem would make it easier to test and generally be "right".

I'll investigate it further, thanks for your help!